# photoswipe - Show the first slide when clicking an external element

Tags: javascript, jquery, photoswipe

Given the standard Photoswipe demo on codepen:

https://codepen.io/dimsemenov/pen/ZYbPJM

I am wondering how to add an element e.g. say a text link within a paragraph of html on the same page, which, when clicked, will open the first image of one of the galleries.

Something like this (which doesn't work of course)

```
<a href="" onClick="opengallery(0)">see gallery</a>
```

I initialize photoswipe from the dom on pageload just like the codepen example, and I have seen the other questions on here that also ask for a similar functionality, but the answers for those also initialize the photoswipe in the onclick, so I don't want to do it that way. Somehow I need to trigger the instance that is already opened.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Was a lot easier than I thought.  Just needed to select the link of the first slide to show, and simulate a click on it. Assumes you have initialized your photoswipe via dom onload as in the default example.

So if I want to show gallery 3 on the page, which is wrapped in a div with and id of `galId3`, I can do something like this:

```
<p>This is a nice product. View <span onclick="initGallery(3)">the gallery</span></p>.
```

Then the js...

```
function initGallery(gal) {
    $('#galId'+gal+' a:first').click();
}
```